# Dynamic parser - read tokens from a separate file

Tags: bison, yacc, context-free-grammar, bnf, jison

Let's say I want to parse my new language that looks like this:

**main.mylang**

```
import "tags.mylang"
cat dog bacon
```

And there's another file `tags.mylang` that looks like this:

```
cat "meow"
dog "woof"
bacon "sizzle"
```

Running `main.mylang` would output

```
meow woof sizzle
```

The problem I'm having is that "cat", "dog", and "bacon" are defined in a separate file, as implemented my the `mylang` developer; i.e., I can't make them part of the grammar beforehand.

Is it possible to dynamically add these tags into the grammar as it's parsing? I don't want to add a wildcard `\w+` or something because I want it to error on unrecognized tags.

**Edit:** I'm writing this using [`jison`](http://zaach.github.com/jison/), which is based on [`bison`](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_4.html#SEC7).

Comment: How do you know a tag is unrecognized, if it might be a variable? Is your grammar such that tags and variables never occur in the same context? Or are tags considered reserved words, even though they might change from time to time?

Comment: @rici: Tags would trump variables. If there is a tag defined for a token, then that token would be treated like a tag, even if there is also a variable under the same name. Similar to how you can define both functions and variables with the same name in many other languages, I guess. I'm starting to think that this is a bad idea, however. I might just want to preface variables with a `$` like PHP or something...

Comment: I tend to agree that letting tags trump variable names is not a great idea. The problem is that "tag files" are not composable; since you must know what variable names cannot be used in order to write a "program", you cannot just add a new tag file to an existing program. Also, it makes it hard to syntax colour. On the other hand, `$` sigils are ugly. Good luck, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that tags all match the pattern for variables, whatever pattern that might be. (`\a\w*`, maybe). Define a dictionary whose keys are tags; the value can be whatever you want to associate with the tag. As I understand it, you can make this dictionary available to both the parser and the lexer by putting it inside the object `parser.yy`.

The lexer rule for variables would be something like this (I don't know much about jison, so this is based on bison+flex):

```
{variable}    if (yytext in yy.tags) { return TAG; } else { return VARIABLE; }
```

If you wanted to have different token types for different tags, (perhaps because tags are aliases for grammatical concepts, or something like that), you could store the token type in the tag dictionary, so that you could return it from the lexer.

In the grammar for tag definition files, you could add a tag definition simply by adding the key and appropriate value to `yy.tags`.

Comment: That looks a lot easier than I thought it would be. Makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the wildcard match `\w+` that you suggest, then use the [YYERROR macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Action-Features.html#Action-Features) to raise your own syntax error when your parser's semantic logic detects an unrecognized/undefined tag.

Comment: This could work, but it means that I can't have 2 different kinds of tokens that "look the same". i.e., if both "tags" and "variables" are defined as `\w+` then the parser won't be able to tell them apart because I don't define them until parse time. Furthermore, it wouldn't generate the right tree.